# Remove 2D line distortion

Tags: 2d, interpolation, distortion

I want to draw a straight line using X and Y pixels but my input data is not streamlined. So I tried to draw the line.And it looks like this How should I remove distortion using interpolation or any other techniques.

Actually my problem is [This is my expected graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu72e.png). But I am getting this distorted image with simulation [Distorted lines and curves because of uneven pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCWuC.png). I want to streamline this graph

Comment: Have a look at least squares regression line : http://www.statisticshowto.com/least-squares-regression-line/

Comment: This will not work for me because i need to draw a pattern using lines and for that i don't have this many pixels for regression

Comment: I have updated my question. please have a look

Comment: You don't need "many" pixels for regression - it is just statistically better for a large data set, but it will still be somewhat effective for a small number of points.